# Cordova 5.0 Gradle build tools Error on Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to import the cordova 5 build android application I have problem with setup the project in Android Studio

I'm getting the problem in cordova.gradle

```
error:No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

But I have installed all the sdk build tools version 19,20,21 & 22.

Comment: check your sdk path in android studio if its correct

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Yeah i have setup everything correctly

Comment: did you find a solution? i am going to try reinstalling the android build tools.

Comment: I answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34776963/69537

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?