# ionic run android failed, error gradle line 64

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

previously I can compile but after I updated my cordova something happended. I got this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Jay\testproject\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.grad
le' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version
 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

I downloaded all the required SDK, what is the problem here?

Comment: You must run all commands as root user. So run "sudo -s". Then re-run back all the commands

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it. I had the build-tools version 20 installed but still was getting this error:

> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools
>   version 19.1.0 or higher.

So I created a directory named `20` within `build-tools` directory, and copied all the files from `sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\*` to `sdk\build-tools\20`. The problem was fixed!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Can you elaborate it further?. The location of build-tools where to create new directory and all

Comment: @Vasanth Hi, in my experience, uninstall all the android installed sdk tools and platforms (entirely remove them) and install them from scratch. If you wonder what you have to install, take a look at this list: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android (make sure you read that document entirely, and pay attention to versions)

Comment: Hi @Meysam I will try doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do two main things:

1. Install android build tools
2. Make them available in your shell, when run the ionic run command.

**Installing the build tools (ver 19.1.0)**

- Open android development studio
- Goto: Configure --> SDK Manager --> select "Android SDK Build-Tools
- select the checkbox "Show Package details" (bottom right)
- review the versions of this package, make sure the 19.1 is selected - u may use newer, but 19.1.0 works.
- Click Apply to make the changes / install it

**Make the build tools available in your shell environment**

Edit ~/.bash_profile by using vi or other shell editor

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Software/android-sdk-macosx/tools:~/Software/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools"
```

(save the file, and exit)
Editing the file, makes sure that for each login those variables will be available, but as we are already in active session, you need to make it available for the current shell env, run the following:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Had the same issue on ubuntu, made a small change on this answer where I had to create a simlink as some packages needed ~/Android/Sdk others ~/Android/sdk. It is working now

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this error for several days, I didn't find any clear explanation

**Till I find this link**, https://tomspencer.dev/blog/2017/05/30/a-guide-to-installing-cordova-on-windows-10

uninstall gradle, cordova, ionic, and anything related then use the steps in the link above to install them all correctly. that worked with me