# Build tool error "Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher"

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-build

I'm importing a cordova project in Android studio and getting this error
**Error:No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.**

I have installed all the Build tools already.
even I have gone through this post but not able to resolve error.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136492/corodova-5-0-gradle-build-tools-error-on-android-studio)
[link2](http://social.gseosem.com/error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the-android-build-tools-version-19-1-0-or-higher/)

I have seen lots of question over OS but didn't get any solution.

help will be appreciated. Thankz

Answer (score 0):

Need correct write "Environment Variables".

https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

Windows:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```